# Cognos Report Studio - avoid Page break in Excel export?

Tags: excel, report, cognos

I'm working on a report in Cognos 10 which is only composed by a list. When I export to Excel and print the report, it breaks a row of the list through pages.

I've already modified the pagination properties of the list with any result..

So, my question is, is there any way to avoid the row break through pages?

Also I would like to ask if somebody know a way to set a header and footers that appears in all pages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please see this IBM doc: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21419957

You can have your administrator change a parameter which will enable a single sheet export.

Comment: Hi toddnappi, thanks for your reply. This isn't exactly my problem, in fact my list will probably never get to the 65000 rows. The problem is when printing the exported report through excel.. It cuts a row by the middle and that row starts on the next page. I would like to set the report so it doesn't cut the rows..

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Cognos export is fine, but when you try to print the excel sheet, it rolls a row onto the next page? If so, then you really just need to play with margins, font size, and orientation to try and get it to fit on one page. If you are unable to get this to work I would remove Cognos from your description and repost just as "how to get excel to print on one page".

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the "Rows per page" property of the list to a maximum value should work.

Answer (score 0):

In case of List, set the **Rows Per Page** property to blank.

To enable the page header, go to **List Headers & Footers** and enable the **List Page Header**.